# discord.js How can I delete the bots message with a Bot ID after 3 seconds?

Tags: discord.js

```
const prefixtest = ">>"

msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

    if(msg.startsWith(prefixtest + "test")) {
        message.delete();
        setTimeout(function() {
           if{message.channel.author.id == "240254129333731328"}{ //this is the bots id
        message.delete();
        }, 3000);
    }
```

Sorry if my english is bad. But I can't solve this problem, i'm trying to find it on internet but nothing. How can I delete other bot messages by using their Bot ID?

Comment: If your code evolved since we talk in my answer, it could be useful to update the code in this post 

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in your code, you are trying to get `.author` property on a [Channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel) instead of a [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message).

So you have to modify your if statement as following :

```js
if (message.author.id === "240254129333731328")
```

Also, you can delay the deletion of a [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) by adding `.delete()` method first parameter an object with a `.timeout` property in it that will represent the delay in milliseconds before the message being deleted. ([See docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete))

```js
message.delete({ timeout: 3000 });
```

So you can modify your code this way :

```js
if(msg.startsWith(prefixtest + "test")) {
    if (message.author.id === "240254129333731328") {
        message.delete({ timeout: 3000 });
    }
}
```

Comment: No. It doesn't work, the bot doesn't delete the other Bots MSG. also it doesn't do a timeout, thank you for helping though

Comment: Can you explain again what behavior do you expect when you type `>>test`?
Do your bot should delete any other messages from other bots 3 seconds after you typed `>>test`?

Comment: Ok lemme explain. So if i type >>clear 5 then my message gets deleted by my bot and the other bots text is still there and then i want it gone in after 3 seconds.

Comment: So if I understand well you want to delete a certain amount of messages posted before you type `>>clear`. I am right?

If so, you should look at [TextBasedChannel.bulkDelete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextBasedChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) method.

Something is also confusing me, when you say "the other bots text is still there" do you mean that you only want to delete messages writed by a bot?

Comment: No, no i mean't one bot. The bot i am trying to delete is called "Vortex", when that bot is deletes with >>clear 5 it doesnt deletes his message itself.

Comment: I'm sorry if I take time to understand, but I try to give you the best answer I can. Do you make your bot sending a message after you typed `>>clear 5` and you are willing to delete this particular message after 3 seconds?

Comment: I will explain again to you sorry my english is not really understandable.
So if i type **>>clear 5** then the "vortex" bot will delete all those 5 messages. and then my message and the vortex bot message doesnt deletes. and so i'M trying to delete my messages first and  then after 3 seconds the  bots message deletes.